# How to change pattern lock viewgroup drawable images dynamically?

Tags: android, android-view

Currently I'm developing a pattern lock application and in that application I extend pattern `View` from `Viewgroup`, it means it can display pattern lock `View` and I am using drawable png image to display pattern `View`.

So, actually I want to change that pattern lock png image dynamically when user selects that image in another `GridView` and display it on the pattern `View`.

**Basically, I want to change only pattern lock theme.**

[Main screenshote of lockscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECCd9.jpg)

**Here this is my pattern lock view xml**

```
    <com.v1.sensoft.halloweenlock.utils.Lock9View
    android:id="@+id/lock_9_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:nodeSrc="@mipmap/ppo"
    app:nodeOnSrc="@mipmap/ppn"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:lineColor="#FFCC00"
    app:lineWidth="8dp" />
```

In that xml `app:nodeSrc="@mipmap/ppo" app:nodeOnSrc="@mipmap/ppn"`is the image to display on pattern lock.

**This is my pattern lock view**

```
public class Lock9View extends ViewGroup {

private Paint paint;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private Canvas canvas;

private List<Pair<NodeView, NodeView>> lineList;
private NodeView currentNode;

private StringBuilder pwdSb;
private CallBack callBack;

private Drawable nodeSrc;
private Drawable nodeOnSrc;

public Lock9View(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public Lock9View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public Lock9View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
}

public Lock9View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr); // TODO api 21
    initFromAttributes(attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

private void initFromAttributes(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    final TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Lock9View, defStyleAttr, 0);

    nodeSrc = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.Lock9View_nodeSrc);
    nodeOnSrc = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.Lock9View_nodeOnSrc);
    int lineColor = Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0);
    lineColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.Lock9View_lineColor, lineColor);
    float lineWidth = 20.0f;
    lineWidth = a.getDimension(R.styleable.Lock9View_lineWidth, lineWidth);

    a.recycle();


    paint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(lineWidth);
    paint.setColor(lineColor);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dm.widthPixels, dm.widthPixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);

    for (int n = 0; n < 9; n++) {
        NodeView node = new NodeView(getContext(), n + 1);
        addView(node);
    }
    lineList = new ArrayList<Pair<NodeView,NodeView>>();
    pwdSb = new StringBuilder();

    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec); 
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    if (!changed) {
        return;
    }
    int width = right - left;
    int nodeWidth = width / 3;
    int nodePadding = nodeWidth / 6;
    for (int n = 0; n < 9; n++) {
        NodeView node = (NodeView) getChildAt(n);
        int row = n / 3;
        int col = n % 3;
        int l = col * nodeWidth + nodePadding;
        int t = row * nodeWidth + nodePadding;
        int r = col * nodeWidth + nodeWidth - nodePadding;
        int b = row * nodeWidth + nodeWidth - nodePadding;
        node.layout(l, t, r, b);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            NodeView nodeAt = getNodeAt(event.getX(), event.getY());
            if (nodeAt == null && currentNode == null) { 
                return true;
            } else { 
                clearScreenAndDrawList(); 
                if (currentNode == null) {
                    currentNode = nodeAt;
                    currentNode.setHighLighted(true);
                    pwdSb.append(currentNode.getNum());
                }
                else if (nodeAt == null || nodeAt.isHighLighted()) {
                    canvas.drawLine(currentNode.getCenterX(), currentNode.getCenterY(), event.getX(), event.getY(), paint);
                } else { 
                    canvas.drawLine(currentNode.getCenterX(), currentNode.getCenterY(), nodeAt.getCenterX(), nodeAt.getCenterY(), paint);
                    nodeAt.setHighLighted(true);
                    Pair<NodeView, NodeView> pair = new Pair<NodeView, NodeView>(currentNode, nodeAt);
                    lineList.add(pair);

                    currentNode = nodeAt;
                    pwdSb.append(currentNode.getNum());
                }

                invalidate();
            }
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            if (pwdSb.length() <= 0) {
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }

            if (callBack != null) {
                callBack.onFinish(pwdSb.toString());
                pwdSb.setLength(0); 
            }

            currentNode = null;
            lineList.clear();
            clearScreenAndDrawList();

            for (int n = 0; n < getChildCount(); n++) {
                NodeView node = (NodeView) getChildAt(n);
                node.setHighLighted(false);
            }

            invalidate();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}


private void clearScreenAndDrawList() {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    for (Pair<NodeView, NodeView> pair : lineList) {
        canvas.drawLine(pair.first.getCenterX(), pair.first.getCenterY(), pair.second.getCenterX(), pair.second.getCenterY(), paint);
    }
}


private NodeView getNodeAt(float x, float y) {
    for (int n = 0; n < getChildCount(); n++) {
        NodeView node = (NodeView) getChildAt(n);
        if (!(x >= node.getLeft() && x < node.getRight())) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!(y >= node.getTop() && y < node.getBottom())) {
            continue;
        }
        return node;
    }
    return null;
}

public void setCallBack(CallBack callBack) {
    this.callBack = callBack;
}


public class NodeView extends View {

    private int num;
    private boolean highLighted;

    private NodeView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NodeView(Context context, int num) {
        this(context);
        this.num = num;
        highLighted = false;
        if (nodeSrc == null) {
            setBackgroundResource(0);
        } else {
            setBackgroundDrawable(nodeSrc);
        }
    }

    public boolean isHighLighted() {
        return highLighted;
    }

    public void setHighLighted(boolean highLighted) {
        this.highLighted = highLighted;
        if (highLighted) {
            if (nodeOnSrc == null) {
                setBackgroundResource(0);
            } else {
                setBackgroundDrawable(nodeOnSrc);
            }
        } else {
            if (nodeSrc == null) {
                setBackgroundResource(0);
            } else {
                setBackgroundDrawable(nodeSrc);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getCenterX() {
        return (getLeft() + getRight()) / 2;
    }

    public int getCenterY() {
        return (getTop() + getBottom()) / 2;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

}

public interface CallBack {

    public void onFinish(String password);

}
```

**Activity**

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    lock9View = (Lock9View) findViewById(R.id.lock_9_view);

    lock9View.setCallBack(new Lock9View.CallBack() {

        public int counter = 0;
        public int buttCounter = 0;

        @Override
        public void onFinish(String password) {
            PATTERN_KEY = prefs.getString("Pattern", "invalid");
                Log.i("Counter","..."+counter);
                if (PATTERN_KEY.equals("invalid")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Options --> Create new Pattern", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    if (password.equals(PATTERN_KEY)) {
                        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(startMain);

                    } else {
                        invalidPattern();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please try again..." +failedCount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
    });
}
```

So,if anyone know please give some idea of that.

Comment: Hi vishal patel, please check  my edits - everything ok?

Comment: yup, you know answer of my question??

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem: do you only need a way to set the bitmap in your custom View or are you also looking for a way to let user select picture etc. ?

Comment: Actually i have gridview and inside gridview i have some images.So,when user select particular image from gridview and replace current image to gridview selected image on pattern lock view.

Comment: can i post my main layout of pattern lock screen for better understanding??

Comment: this is my main screen layout http://imgur.com/a/sOani

Comment: If anything, I'd like to see the code in the Activity where you'd like to call the View to update itself with the new picture.

Comment: See this on pattern lock view (public class NodeView extends View) and also check xml

Comment: So you need a method `Lock9View.setTheme(Drawable myDrawable)` and then this method will copy `myDrawable` to `Lock9View.bitmap` and so the Drawable will be used as View background?